# Reactive Extensions Group By, Unique BufferWindow till time span with cancellation

Tags: system.reactive

I have a Hot stream of events coming of following type:

```
Event
{
    string name;
    int state ; // its 1 or 2 ie active or unactive
}
```

there is a function which provides parent name of given name - string GetParent(string name)

I need to buffer event per parent for 2 minutes, if during this 2 minute , i recv any event for child with state =2 for a given parent , this buffer should cancel and should output 0 otherwise i get the count of the events recvd .

I know I have to use GroupBy to partition, and then buffer and then count but i am unable to think of a way by which i create Buffer which is unique per parent, i though of using Distinct but this doesnt solve the problem, for i only dont want to create buffer till the parent is active (as once the parent's buffer gets cancelled or 2 minutes is over, the parent buffer can be created again)
So I understand I need to create a custom buffer which checks the condition for creating buffer, but how do i do this via reactive extensions.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
regards

Thanks Brandon for your help. This is the main program I am using for testing. Its not working.As I am new to reactive extension problem can be in the way i am testing

```
namespace TestReactive
{
class Program
{
    static int abc = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Subject<AEvent> memberAdded = new Subject<AEvent>();
        //ISubject<AEvent, AEvent> syncedSubject = new ISubject<AEvent, AEvent>();
        var timer = new Timer { Interval = 5 };

        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => MyElapsedMethod(sender, e, memberAdded);

        var bc = memberAdded.Subscribe();
        var cdc = memberAdded.GroupBy(e => e.parent)
  .SelectMany(parentGroup =>
  {
      var children = parentGroup.Publish().RefCount();
      var inactiveChild = children.SkipWhile(c => c.state != 2).Take(1).Select(c => 0);
      var timer1 = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
      var activeCount = children.TakeUntil(timer1).Count();

      return Observable.Amb(activeCount, inactiveChild)
          .Select(count => new { ParentName = parentGroup.Key, Count = count });

  });

      Observable.ForEachAsync(cdc, x => WriteMe("Dum Dum " + x.ParentName+x.Count));
        // group.Dump("Dum");


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void WriteMe(string sb)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
    static void MyElapsedMethod(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, Subject<AEvent> s)
    {
        AEvent ab = HelperMethods.GetAlarm();
        Console.WriteLine(abc + " p =" + ab.parent + ", c = " + ab.name + " ,s = " + ab.state);
        s.OnNext(ab);

    }

}
```

}

```
    public static AEvent GetAlarm()
    {
        if (gp> 4)
            gp = 1;
        if (p > 4)
            p = 1;
        if (c > 4)
            c = 1;
        AEvent a = new AEvent();
        a.parent = "P" + gp + p;
        a.name = "C" + gp + p + c;
        if (containedKeys.ContainsKey(a.name))
        {
            a.state = containedKeys[a.name];
            if (a.state == 1)
                containedKeys[a.name] = 2;
            else
                containedKeys[a.name] = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            containedKeys.TryAdd(a.name, 1);

        }
        gp++; p++; c++;

        return a;

    }
```

So this method , generates a event for Parent at each tick. It generates event for parent P11,P22,P33,P44 with State =1 and then followed by events for Parent P11,P22,P33,P44 with State =2
I am using Observable.ForEach to print the result, I see its being called 4 times and after that its nothing, its like ***cancellation of group is not happening***

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that a two minute buffer for each group should open as soon as the first event for that group is seen, and close after two minutes or a zero state is seen, then I think the following works:

```
public static IObservable<EventCount> EventCountByParent(
    this IObservable<Event> source, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Create<EventCount>(observer => source.GroupByUntil(
        evt => GetParent(evt.Name),
        evt => evt,
        group =>
        @group.Where(evt => evt.State == 2)
              .Merge(Observable.Timer(
                  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), scheduler).Select(_ => Event.Null)))
              .SelectMany(
                  go =>
                  go.Aggregate(0, (acc, evt) => (evt.State == 2 ? 0 : acc + 1))
              .Select(count => new EventCount(go.Key, count))).Subscribe(observer));
}
```

With EventCount (implementing equality overrides for testing) as:

```
public class EventCount
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly int _count;

    public EventCount(string name, int count)
    {
        _name = name;
        _count = count;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public int Count { get { return _count; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}, Count: {1}", _name, _count);
    }

    protected bool Equals(EventCount other)
    {
        return string.Equals(_name, other._name) && _count == other._count;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((EventCount) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((_name != null ? _name.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ _count;
        }
    }
}
```

And Event as:

```
public class Event
{
    public static Event Null = new Event(string.Empty, 0);

    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly int _state;

    public Event(string name, int state)
    {
        _name = name;
        _state = state;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name;  } }
    public int State { get { return _state; } }
}
```

I did a quick (i.e. not exhaustive) test with Rx-Testing:

```
public class EventCountByParentTests : ReactiveTest
{
    private readonly TestScheduler _testScheduler;

    public EventCountByParentTests()
    {
        _testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void IsCorrect()
    {
        var source = _testScheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).Ticks, new Event("A", 1)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20).Ticks, new Event("B", 1)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).Ticks, new Event("A", 1)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40).Ticks, new Event("B", 1)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50).Ticks, new Event("A", 1)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).Ticks, new Event("B", 2)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(70).Ticks, new Event("A", 1)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(140).Ticks, new Event("A", 1)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150).Ticks, new Event("A", 1)));

        var results = _testScheduler.CreateObserver<EventCount>();

        var sut = source.EventCountByParent(_testScheduler).Subscribe(results);

        _testScheduler.Start();

        results.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).Ticks, new EventCount("B", 0)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(130).Ticks, new EventCount("A", 4)),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(260).Ticks, new EventCount("A", 2)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like....

```
source.GroupBy(e => GetParent(e.name))
      .SelectMany(parentGroup =>
      {
          var children = parentGroup.Publish().RefCount();
          var inactiveChild = children.SkipWhile(c => c.state != 2).Take(1).Select(c => 0);
          var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
          var activeCount = children.TakeUntil(timer).Count();

          return Observable.Amb(activeCount, inactiveChild)
              .Select(count => new { ParentName = parentGroup.Key, Count = count };
      });
```

This will give you a sequence of { ParentName, Count } objects.

Comment: Hello brandon,Thanks for help. I am trying to test it. I created a subject<event>